# How to import Cronjob using impexes?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I have written the following impexes in:

```
trainingcore/resources/trainingcore/import/common/cronjob.impex
```

The impexes are :

```
     INSERT_UPDATE ServicelayerJob;code[unique=true];springId;
    ;myJob;myJob;

     INSERT_UPDATE 
     MyCronJob;code[unique=true];job(code);sessionLanguage(isocode);categoryCode;thresholdTime;
    ;myCronJob;myJob;en;xyz;5;

    # Fires every 1 minute
    INSERT_UPDATE Trigger;cronJob(code)[unique=true];active;cronExpression;
    ;myCronJob;true;0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *
```

But when I'm updating the system, the impexes are not being loaded. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These impexes are not picked up automatically. You need to have a System setup in your project where you need to add a link to the file.

From the location of your file, I assume you started from the starter template for a core project. In that case, there should be a file `CoreSystemSetup` in your core project. Somewhere in the location `<classpathprefix/>setup/CoreSystemSetup`

You need to add your file here as a new line in this file.
This will be something like this

```
@SystemSetup(extension = TrainingCoreCoreConstants.EXTENSIONNAME)
public class CoreSystemSetup extends AbstractSystemSetup
{
    public static final String IMPORT_ACCESS_RIGHTS = "accessRights";

    @SystemSetup(type = Type.ESSENTIAL, process = Process.ALL)
    public void createEssentialData(final SystemSetupContext context)
    {
        importImpexFile(context, "/trainingcore/import/common/essential-data.impex");
        importImpexFile(context, "/trainingcore/import/common/cronjob.impex");
    }
}
```

You can also add this file in the project data part of this setup file. Depending on your needs.